# how to put svg image on one side 3d cube using css3?

Tags: html, css, svg, 3d

I've created a cube and the last step is to put a picture on the "back" side. I can link a regular image and its working using following code:

```
.cube .back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(pika.svg);    
}
```

But, when I try to link my svg file as an img the whole image is not showing.
I have three separate layers in my svg but only two show. What am I doing wrong?

here's the svg code:
http://pastebin.com/H6tnHk0p

Comment: We're going to have to see the code of your SVG or perhaps a live example in order to show you

Comment: the part that is not showing up is a linked part of the svg. if i embed it and link to svg will that change things

Answer (score 0):

SVGs that are included as an image (eg. via `<img>` or `background-image`) cannot reference other external objects.  That includes images, CSS etc.  Your SVG references an external PNG file.

What you can do is include the PNG by embedding it as a base64 data URL.

This restriction is a deliberate browser security measure.